# CSS border-left is not working on safari how can I make?

Tags: html, css

border-left not working on Safari

It works perfectly Chrome browser.

Safari is not supporting border-left ?

CODE:

```css
.card-txt {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-color: white;
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(to bottom, #c88cff, #9c5bd8);
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-style: italic;
  height: 40px;
  width: 240px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  text-indent: 3px;
  border-image-slice:1;
}
```

```html
            <div class="card-top">
              <div class="card-image"><img src="clock.svg" alt="Clock" width="100" height="100"></div>
              <div class="card-txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
            </div>
```

[Computer Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqVMr.png)

[Safari Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1lO0.png)

Comment: Try moving `border-color` below `border-image-soure`

Comment: @Kielstra But i need linear gradient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a safari but this code maybe work

```css
.card-txt {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: white;
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(to bottom, #c88cff, #9c5bd8);
  border-width:0 0 0 3px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-style: italic;
  height: 40px;
  width: 240px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  text-indent: 3px;
  border-image-slice:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-top">
  <div class="card-image"><img src="clock.svg" alt="Clock" width="100" height="100"></div>
  <div class="card-txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</div>
```